# Python scrapy yield to .json file not working

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, macos, scrapy

I want to use Scrapy to extract the titles of different books in a url and output/store them as an array of dictionaries in a json file.

***Here is my code:***

```
import scrapy

class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "books"
    star_urls = [ 
        "http://books.toscrape.com"
    ]

def parse(self, response):
    titles = response.css("article.product_pod h3 a::attr(title)").getall()
    for title in titles:
        yield {"title": title}
```

***Here is what i put in the terminal:***

```
scrapy crawl books -o books.json
```

The books.json file is created but is empty.

I checked that I was in the right directory and venv but it still doesn't work.

**However**:

Earlier, i deployed this spider to scrape the whole html data and write it to a books.html file and everything worked.

***Here is my code for this:***

```
import scrapy

class BooksSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "books"
    star_urls = [ 
        "http://books.toscrape.com"
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        with open("books.html", "wb") as file:
            file.write(response.body)
```

***and here is what I put in my terminal:***

```
scrapy crawl books
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Edit:

inputing `response.css('article.product_pod h3 a::attr(title)').getall()`

into the scrapy shell outputs:

```
['A Light in the Attic', 'Tipping the Velvet', 'Soumission', 'Sharp Objects', 'Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind', 'The Requiem Red', 'The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job', 'The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull', 'The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics', 'The Black Maria', 'Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)', "Shakespeare's Sonnets", 'Set Me Free', "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)", 'Rip it Up and Start Again', 'Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991', 'Olio', 'Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849', 'Libertarianism for Beginners', "It's Only the Himalayas"]
```

Comment: Have you verified that your `.getall()` actually returns something using a debugger or calling `print()`?

Comment: I first played around with it in the scrapy shell and got a list of titles so it does return something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now run the code.It should work

```
import scrapy

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):

        titles = response.css('.product_pod')
        for title in titles:
            yield {
                "title": title.css('h3 a::attr(title)').get()
                #"title": title.css('h3 a::text').get()
            }
```

**Output:**

```
 [
    {
        "title": "A Light in the Attic"
    },
    {
        "title": "Tipping the Velvet"
    },
    {
        "title": "Soumission"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sharp Objects"
    },
    {
        "title": "Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Requiem Red"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Dirty Little Secrets of Getting Your Dream Job"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Coming Woman: A Novel Based on the Life of the Infamous Feminist, Victoria Woodhull"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Boys in the Boat: Nine Americans and Their Epic Quest for Gold at the 1936 Berlin Olympics"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Black Maria"
    },
    {
        "title": "Starving Hearts (Triangular Trade Trilogy, #1)"
    },
    {
        "title": "Shakespeare's Sonnets"
    },
    {
        "title": "Set Me Free"
    },
    {
        "title": "Scott Pilgrim's Precious Little Life (Scott Pilgrim #1)"
    },
    {
        "title": "Rip it Up and Start Again"
    },
    {
        "title": "Our Band Could Be Your Life: Scenes from the American Indie Underground, 1981-1991"
    },
    {
        "title": "Olio"
    },
    {
        "title": "Mesaerion: The Best Science Fiction Stories 1800-1849"
    },
    {
        "title": "Libertarianism for Beginners"
    },
    {
        "title": "It's Only the Himalayas"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but the json file remains empty. Do you know what it might be?

Comment: terminal command to run: `scrapy crawl quotes -o data.json`